# Detect iOS version using Telerik AppBuilder (Cordova.js)

Tags: mobile, telerik, kendo-mobile

How do I detect the version of iOS using Telerik AppBuilder (Cordova.js)? That would be great if the same method was used for finding the version for any mobile platform, but I need it specifically for iOS.

Please let me know if there is any other information I need to provide.

Thank you in advance.

---

**Additional answer**

Here is the information found in the mobileOS object:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the mobileOS object. It is filled is all kinds of good info about the device that is running the app.

```
// isiPad: Must be mobile OS AND ipad
var isiPad = kendo.support.mobileOS && kendo.support.mobileOS.device == 'ipad';
if (isiPad) {
```

Comment: Yes, the mobileOS object contains a lot of useful information, including the version of the OS. I gave another answer to this question in my question to provide all that information. Thank you!